# Terminal Stalls at Login

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac OS X Terminal not logging in](https://superuser.com/questions/131670/mac-os-x-terminal-not-logging-in)

When I open my Terminal.app the terminal opens, but nothing shows. The title bar says login, so I assume its a problem with /usr/bin/login.
Confusingly when I restart it works for a bit and then again stops working.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the session shell in : Preferences -> Start -> Open shells with command : /bin/bash (for example).

1. Try with the same shell you use normally.
2. If the problem persists, try with another shell (like /bin/zsh).

With this we should see where is the problem (/usr/bin/login, or .bashrc or any .rc file)

Comment: No matter what shell I use, I cannot get past it. Even if I do specify /bin/zsh it says login in the titlebar.

Comment: Well strange. It shouldn't say "login" when you specify /bin/zsh. It should bypass /usr/bin/login and directly run /bin/zsh.

Did you put something in a .profile or .bashrc (or another .rc) file ?

Comment: Terminal always creates a terminal session via /usr/bin/login. If you specify a custom shell or other command, it passes that as an argument to login and login runs the command instead of the user's default shell.