# How to change mac terminal window from login to bash?

Tags: mac, terminal

My terminal window in mac is showing login and not bash.The terminal window with login title works like notepad,i want to change back to bash .How can i do that ?please help me out.thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "works like notepad"? Did you accidentally change your default shell to a text editor, so login(1) is invoking a text editor? What does `id -P` report as the shell (at the end of the line) for your account?

Comment: I posted an answer to the same question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/131670/mac-os-x-terminal-not-logging-in/286135#286135).

Comment: @gaeron -- Please don't post an answer like the one you've written here, use the comment functionality - use the flag for mod attention

Comment: Not the same question. This one is simply about what is displayed in the title, the other one about a completely non-working terminal.

Comment: @Spiff, what Warrior means by "works like notepad" is that there is no program currently responding to terminal input, and therefore anything one types is merely echoed to the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the Terminal menu item, then on Preferences. Under "When creating a new Terminal window:" click on "Execute this command (specify complete path):" and put in "/bin/bash".

Comment: +1. I'd also add a reminder that switching from login(1) to bash(1) means your Terminal shells will now just be interactive shells, not login shells, so they will source {/etc/,~/.}bashrc instead of {/etc/,~/.}profile, so you may need to looks at those scripts to make sure you've got the right content in the right place.

Comment: As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, any custom command you use that is listed in /etc/shells will be run as a login session.

Comment: Note that this answer is merely a workaround and doesn't identify or resolve the problem being encountered. Also, it may not work on Lion. The issue is that the `login` program is hanging for some reason while trying to create a login session. A common cause of this is being on a network with Directory Services (Open Directory) and the server is unresponsive. `login` has to get your user information from the server in order to log in. This answer may be relying on Terminal not creating a login session, and therefore avoiding communicating with the server.